# PowerShell ValidateSet equivalent for C# function parameter?

Tags: c#, parameters

How can I ensure, that the parameter `info` of my public function only takes values of `leverage`, `fees`, `margin`?

Coming from PowerShell, is there something like `[ValidateSet("leverage", "fees", "margin")]`?

I was thinking about using an enumeration, but that only allows for integers.

```
public int DoSomething(string info=null, string pair=null)
```

Comment: Write validation at the start of your method..  Also, no, enumeration does not only allow for integers.

Comment: Thanks for replying, could you please elaborate?

Comment: And what are you doing with info in function? If you mostly compare it (so, use it as a membef of set, not as string) - then enum is a good choice.

Comment: ValidateSet is defined in System.Management.Automation